# Bloc - No list state emitted from a Map

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Currently in my application, I manage a key-value map, in that variable I have a list which removes and appends, as time goes by it increases and I emit it to my Bloc state to be able to change the UI, however it does not change it, but appends it, and removes it but does not change it, does anyone know why ?

```
 void _onShape(
    AddShapeEvent event,
    Emitter<DrawingAnnotationState> emit,
  ) {
    final Shape shape = event.shape;

    final newMap = Map.of(state.shapesByPages); // getting the map in state

    /// The shape is added to the page
    newMap[currentPage]!.removeWhere((l) => l.id == shape.id);

    newMap[currentPage]!.add(shape);


    emit(state.copyWith(
      status: Status.success,
      lineList: newMap[currentPage],
      shapeMap: newMap,
    ));
  }
```

**DrawingAnnotationState **

```
enum DrawingAnnotationStatus { initial, loading, success, failure }

extension DrawingAnnotationStatusX on DrawingAnnotationStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == DrawingAnnotationStatus.initial;
  bool get isSuccess => this == DrawingAnnotationStatus.success;
  bool get isFailure => this == DrawingAnnotationStatus.failure;
  bool get isLoading => this == DrawingAnnotationStatus.loading;
}

class DrawingAnnotationState extends Equatable {
  final DrawingAnnotationStatus status;

  final List<DrawnShape> lineList;

  final Map<int, List<DrawnShape>> shapesByPages;

  final String failureMessage;

  const DrawingAnnotationState({
    this.status = DrawingAnnotationStatus.initial,
    this.lineList = const [],
    this.shapesByPages = const {},
    this.failureMessage = "",
  });

  DrawingAnnotationState copyWith({
    DrawingAnnotationStatus? status,
    List<DrawnShape>? lineList,
    Map<int, List<DrawnShape>>? shapesByPages,
    String? failureMessage,
  }) {
    return DrawingAnnotationState(
      status: status ?? this.status,
      lineList: lineList ?? this.lineList,
      shapesByPages: shapesByPages ?? this.shapesByPages,
      failureMessage: failureMessage ?? this.failureMessage,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props {
    return [
      status,
      lineList,
      shapesByPages,
      failureMessage,
    ];
  }
}
```

------ EDIT

I see here, my List is a list of a class that has another list, that list is the one that is increasing, the add and remove I only do it so that they are not duplicated.

Comment: I don't see any code to actually change `state.shapesByPages`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, in the lineList state, at the end, that changes cause' i remove and i add a new one, but the emit does not take it into account at the moment.  but if I make another emit with a different status, now it works

Comment: Can you show your equality comparer for the DrawingAnnotationState? How do you figure out if two states are the same (ignored) or different?

Comment: Done, i edit it

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue with List yesterday, I assume you 've remove then add the same item to `shapesByPages`, I guess Bloc compare Map with same keys and values doesn't trigger builder, even create new instance of Map

My workaround is emit empty map first:

```
emit(shapeMap: {})
```

then

```
emit(state.copyWith(
      status: Status.success,
      lineList: newMap[currentPage],
      shapeMap: newMap,
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that's what I wouldn't like, because I would broadcast twice and it's not optimal. I would like to see a way to compare and let the emitter know that there was a change.